# How to give click event in jquery previous result

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the code like this.

```
switch (action) {
            case "default":
                querystring = 'action=' + action;// this will load data in table 
                break;
            case "add":
                querystring = 'action=' + action + '&value=' + data;// this will create new item
                break;
            case "edit":
                querystring = 'action=' + action + '&value=' + data + '&id='+id;// this will edit old item
                break;
        }
```

The Output for **case"default"** will show in table like this.
[image]

input for **edit** and **add** function, i have used **jquery ui dialog**
for add new field its working fine. but for edit function i cant able to give **.click event**

**My Edit event given like this**

```
$('.iname-edit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();            
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var value = $(this).closest('.list-item');
        edit_load(value, id);

    });
    function edit_load(value, id) {
        edit_dialog = $('#popup').dialog({
            title: 'Rename Old Type'

        });
        edit_dialog.dialog("open");
        $('#iname').val(value);
    }
```

But dialog box not opening..

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your `Console`?

Comment: how to get error in console log..

Comment: If you are using Chrome, pull out the developer tools by pressing the `F12` button, and look in the `Console` tab.

Comment: F12 works in firefox (sometimes?) and IE/Edge as well

Comment: No errors nothing showed in console

Comment: i have tried simple alert function it to not running but this all working if checked form outer the result table..